# Timeline for developing a “retroscope” – looking back in time

Tags: science-based, technology, physics, spacetime-dimensions, light

Some time before 2020, a small group of physicists publishes a theory about how photons (and maybe other particles, too) “remember” their path and previous states, i.e. it should be possible to determine or calculate the position in space-time of a captured photon with arbitrary precision. The theory proofs to be viable.

How long into the future would it take to build a detector-computer machine, a *retroscope*, that …

- … catches a single photon and accurately tells its history for …

  - … a microsecond ago?
  - … a year ago?
  - … its entire existence?
- … continually catches photons and can correlate their spacial-temporal positions to generate a retrospect photograph, a *retrogram*, of a …

  - … galaxy?
  - … star?
  - … human being on Earth?
  - … cell?
- … solves recent crimes?
- … revolutionizes the study of human history?
- … fits inside a human hand?

If you could look back in time this way, could you also look forward?

Comment: I like the question, but I think that it is primarily opinion based, because "10 years" or "100 years" are both acceptable answers

Comment: @PavelJanicek I would be okay with a precision of “years”, “decades”, “centuries”, “millennia” for the various steps.

Answer (score 1):

On Earth? A few zipposeconds (I haven't done the calculations) plus 8 minutes. When you see someone in the daytime, the light comes from the sun, bounces off them and then into your eye.  You would trace the light beam back to the person.  In other words, you would 'see' them. You could then trace the light back to the sun but you knew it came from there anyway.

The same with anything else that you can see. You can only go back to the source of illumination. There aren't many perfectly reflective surfaces in the universe so usually this is two steps - one to the object being observed and two to the original light source.

Photons are created when they leave the light source. They don't have any history before that. Nothing would be different. We already do see back in time.

Comment: The idea is that you could take a picture of the sun 8**+** minutes ago on Earth if you collected enough photons that had been there at that specific time, no matter what each of them hit or passed in the meantime, i.e. without pointing the camera/retroscope directly at the sun.